# Sql Server 2008 Agent Log Purge

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-log

Today i realize on my Sql Server 2008 disk space is full.
When i check disk usage, i see sql agent logs as belown picture.
How to clean these log files ?
I searched somebody says that delete phsically from disk but somebody says dont delete physically. I confused.
Should i delete physicaly from disk or any other way for delete log files?
Am i need to close server agent when the progressing of this cleaning task?

Thanks,

[image: Disk Usage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a SQL agent job that runs daily to roll the active error log file over. If you have need for more than a weeks worth of errors, you can set it to run weekly instead.

```
exec sp_cycle_errorlog
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create maintenance plan for log history cleanup and schedule it at a suitable frequency.